# Spring Boot Application No Body Returned for Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, odata, olingo

we are building a web service with Java 11, Spring Boot 2.7.3 & Apache Olingo 4.8.0 everything was working fine until we test a request and expecting a extremely huge response. The response should be over 1 GB. But the response is empty with insomnia:

[image]

Then I write a piece of script with Python 3.8.10 and printed the response.content:

```
b''
```

Same error with curl.

Anyone could please advise? Thanks in advance!

---

Update:

I can confirm the issue is associated with Apache Olingo OData 4.0 Java. Empty response is returned by ODataSerializer.entityCollection() when we passed 4024538 entities. I am wondering if anyone could advise?

Comment: This is probably not answerable without any code. Please post the code producing the response.

Comment: Did you try it with curl? It could be a problem with insomnia and not with your app.

Comment: @dimnnv same error with curl

Comment: @puelo it works perfectly fine when the response is smaller.

Comment: @L.Bai does the response fit in JVM memory? It's worth checking Xmx JVM parameter as well as service exceptions.

Comment: @dimnnv the JVM mem consumption is as expected and the application works perfectly fine, we are only missing the response.

Comment: @L.Bai, Try writing a small response directly to the response body to determine whether there is no body return response due to a large amount of data (>1GB).

Comment: @life888888 thanks I can confirm less than 1gb data can be returned properly.

Comment: @L.Bai, If the data less than 1GB can be returned normally, but the data larger than 1GB cannot be returned normally, it can be guessed that (1) the server-side processing time is too long, resulting in (1a) server-side timeout or (1b) client-side timeout (2) because The amount of data is too large, causing related memory problems on the server side (3) The above should be able to execute the console output of the Spring Boot Application from the command line to see if there is an output-related error message.

Comment: @life888888 Thanks for your reply:1.yes server side processing is long but we can not observe any error or timeout in application log(1a) and I have disabled client side timeout(1b) 2.We already assigned enough memory and no memory issue has been observed. 3.I can not find any error in application log.